# 2D grid game problem - Storing pane positions for 2D Array in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a game in Java on a 2D grid of 10x10 cells. Your character is a miner and he moves with WASD collecting gold. 10 gold and you win. I can create the board, and generate random positions for the gold and player and add them to the board.

Initially, I was getting a duplicate child error whenever the player moved. I fixed this by clearing the board and repopulating the board with the cells and player. However, the gold is placed at random positions when the board is first created. So now, if I include the gold again after clearing the board, they repopulate at random spots again, different from the first. I'm very new to multi-dimensional arrays and panes, so am unsure of how to code this. Thank you!

```
    //instantiate cell class
    Cell[][] cell = new Cell[10][10];
    //instantiate player class
    Player player = new Player();


    //create map 
    for (int i = 0; i < engine.getSize(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < engine.getSize(); j++) {
            pane.add(engine.getMap()[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);
        }
    }

    //add player to random position on map
    Random random = new Random();
    player.setPlayerRow(random.nextInt(engine.getSize()));
    player.setPlayerCol(random.nextInt(engine.getSize()));
    pane.add(cell[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = player, player.getPlayerCol(),
            player.getPlayerRow());


    //add gold to random positions on map 
    while(goldCount < 10) {
            int randomRow2 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            int randomCol2 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            if (randomRow2 != player.getPlayerRow() && randomCol2 != player.getPlayerCol()) {
                pane.add(cell[randomRow2][randomCol2] = new Gold(), randomCol2, randomRow2);
                goldCount++;
            }
        }

    //listener for player movement
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            player.setPlayerRow(player.getPlayerRow()-1);

            //add player, then create grid 
            pane.add(cell[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = player,  player.getPlayerCol(),
                    player.getPlayerRow());

            for (int i = 0; i < engine.getSize(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < engine.getSize(); j++) {
                    pane.add(engine.getMap()[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);
                }
            }

    //re-add gold somehow?
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep up with the position of the gold and put it back in that position after the board is reloaded.

Comment: Sounds like the "Duplicate child" issue would be much simpler to solve and probably more effifient than repopulating everything each time the player moves;  just use [`GridPane.setConstraints`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setConstraints(javafx.scene.Node,int,int)) instead of `add`.

Comment: @fabian that sounds really good, if I can solve the duplicate issue another way that would make my life heaps easier. I've never seen the setConstraints method before. Can you expand on what you mean? How would I use that to remove the gold as the player moves over them? Appreciate the help!

Comment: `Node`s contain a `properties`property providing a way for the parent to store/modify any layout parameters that apply to that child. `setConstraints` sets the properties that denote the position of a child and tells the parent to update itself in case it's a `GridPane`.What `add` does is set the same properties and add the child to the list of`children`.You could achieve the exact same effect by replacing `g.add(c,x,y)`with`GridPane.setConstraints(c,x,y);g.getChildren().add(c);`Since you add a node to the same parent twice that fails the second time.Updating only the constraints works though.